# Ubuntu with GNOME 3 - How can I remove the background color of icons on selection?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-shell

[image: ScreenShot showing the bg behind desktop icon]

In the above image, we can see a blue background on the user folder on selection. 
1. How can I get it removed?
2. How to reduce the margin between two desktop icons?

I searched a lot of places and got no working solution. Please help.